# Implement custom marker - jsartoolkit5

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, markers, jsartoolkit

I am building an Augmented Reality project with [jsartoolkit5](https://github.com/artoolkit/jsartoolkit5) together with `Three.js` and, I would like to implement a custom marker as shown in the following [example](https://artoolkit.github.io/jsartoolkit5/examples/pattern_threejs.html). The markers are imported through the following code:

```
  arController.loadMarker('Data/patt.hiro', function(markerId) {
    var markerRoot = arController.createThreeMarker(markerId);
    markerRoot.add(sphere);
    arScene.scene.add(markerRoot);
  });

  arController.loadMarker('Data/patt.kanji', function(markerId) {
    var markerRoot = arController.createThreeMarker(markerId);
    markerRoot.add(torus);
    arScene.scene.add(markerRoot);
  });
```

This is instead part of the code of the file, `patt.hiro`, containing the information of the marker:

```
 234 235 240 233 240 234 240 235 240 237 240 238 240 240 240 232
 229 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 228
 227 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 239
 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 236 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 234 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 236 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 231 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 229 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 225 149 240 240 186 216 225 174 240 240 240 237 238 240 240 240
 150 107 238 231  75 208 115 147 238 228 223 226 237 180 226 240
 150  62 181 213  62 187 113 169 197  72  29 237 120  50  53 207
 149  63  47  78  53 184 113 101 142   5 150 150  45 217 186  83
 121  84 220 222  58 180 121  92 128 109 237 124 155 232 161  64
 149  71 240 240  76 210  98 109 122 108 240 129  51 119 161 155
 149 186 240 240  98 219 135 152 207 191 236 227 152  77 175 209
 235 235 240 233 240 234 240 235 240 236 240 238 240 240 240 240
 229 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 227 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 236 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 234 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 236 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 232 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 229 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 225 156 240 240 186 216 225 186 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 150 117 240 231  72 206 115 162 240 232 223 237 240 180 226 240
 150  74 187 213  51 184 103 168 197  78  29 237 120  50  53 216
 144  77  51  74  61 184 106 101 142   5 150 152  52 217 186  85
 117  89 219 219  65 184 121  92 128 100 236 125 156 240 170  73
 148  71 240 240  76 210 109 109 121  99 240 137  51 120 166 164
 140 186 240 240  98 220 150 156 207 192 236 230 152  77 176 212
 234 235 240 233 240 234 240 235 240 236 240 238 240 240 240 233
 229 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 239
 227 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 234 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 232 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 235 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 232 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 228 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 225 156 240 240 182 212 225 180 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 150 116 238 228  66 205 115 151 238 236 225 240 240 180 226 240
 156  84 186 211  47 184 109 170 200  92  30 240 120  50  53 216
 147  83  51  73  50 184 106 110 148  17 151 150  45 217 186  85
 127  98 219 219  58 179 109 101 128 107 237 125 155 240 163  72
 155  86 240 240  76 201  85 108 121  95 232 137  51 118 153 155
 149 189 240 240  98 220 141 154 206 178 235 230 152  77 175 209
```

My current issue is that I am not able to understand how to convert a `jpeg` image, for instance, into the following set of data and numbers.
Do you have an idea on the file format and how to reach such result?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it may be helpful for someone in the future, I have found this [tool](http://flash.tarotaro.org/blog/2009/07/12/mgo2/) that helps converting an image into a `.patt` file.

Comment: There's a tool for this now https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/three.js/examples/marker-training/examples/generator.html